# PHP Expression: Why var_dump(false < -1) = true?

Tags: php, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

Can you please explain how PHP execute this code and the result is `true`?

```
var_dump( (false < -1) ); //bool(true)
```

Comment: For the same reason as `false < ((bool)-1)`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php -1 is considered TRUE

Comment: @hakre: how PHP deals with this? it converts booleans to number or number to boolean first?

Comment: http://php.net/language.operators.comparison#language.operators.comparison.types

Answer (score 4):

False is boolean type, and from PHP maunal:

> -1 is considered TRUE, like any other non-zero (whether negative or positive) number!

Resource: http://php.net/bool

Comment: but why php not converted false to 0?

Comment: @Akam: because the first operand dictates the type to be used in the comparison.

Comment: Okay, now found the reference, it's even further: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18597556/367456

Comment: @hakre: then what about -1 < true = false? and -1 < false = false?

Comment: See my linked answer it has the comparison reference table linked. you find each case there. If you've got more than one operator (like in your comment), take also operator precedence into account.

Answer (score 1):

For comparison PHP is [casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) values to same types.

If `-1` is casted to boolen, that is `true`, so if you compare `false < true` then `true` is correct value.

Comment: Exactly. The core idea is that `(true > false) === true`